# Why selector ":button" doesn't work with click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm using the Jquery selector ":button" but doesn't work combine with click event....

```
$(":button").click(function () {
   alert("click");
   return false;
});
```

Comment: are you sure? http://jsfiddle.net/7zs5W/

Comment: Are you running that code *before* the button is part of the DOM?

Comment: I'm using <input type="submit" value="Create" /> is different for input?

Comment: @mrojas: [`:button`](http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/) only matches `<button` and `<input type="button"`.

Comment: I running that code in the doc ready...

Comment: If you're not sure when the button is loaded you can try hooking it with the .live() function. In that way it doesn't matter when it appears, jquery will always bind it.

Comment: @OmerAmsel `.live` is deprecated... use `.on`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you put your code in the jQuery document ready function:

```
$(function(){

   /** YOUR CODE **/
   $(":button").click(function () {
       alert("click");
       return false;
   });

});
```

But as I see from [your comments on the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399236/why-selector-button-doesnt-work-with-click-event/11399304#comment15029142_11399236), you actually might want to do this:

```
$(function(){

   /** YOUR CODE **/
   $(":submit").click(function () {
       alert("click");
       return false;
   });

});
```

Comment: I see the problem, thank you very much!

Comment: @mrojas no problem ^_^ happy to help :-)

Comment: @mrojas remember to select an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

You may have following issues;

- may be forget to add jQuery library in your code
- may be you forget `$(document).ready()` wrapper i.e

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // place all jquery code here
    $(':button').on('click', function() {
       alert('click');
       return false;
    });
  });
  ```
- `:button` may be added to DOM dynamically i.e after page load

  In that case you should try:

  ```
  $('body').on('click', ':button', function() {
    alert('Click');
    return false;
  });
  ```

#### According to your comment above

You can try this:

```
$('input[type=submit]').on('click', function() {
   alert('click');
   return false;
});
```

**OR**

```
$('input[type=submit]').on('click', function(e) {
   alert('click');
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's [`:button`](http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/) selector is equivalent to `$('button, input[type="button"]')`.  Therefore, it won't match your control: `<input type="submit" value="Create" />`.

Try using `$('input[type="submit"]')` instead (you can use `$(':submit')`, but `[type="submit"]` may be faster).

Comment: I believe that `[type='submit']` and `:submit` might take the same to close the same amount of time (I have not tested this)

Comment: @Neal: The jQuery docs (http://api.jquery.com/submit-selector/) say `[type="submit"]` may be faster.

Comment: @Neal: I haven't tested it, I'm just doing what the docs say :-P